# Optimal binning for numerical data using R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, distribution, binning

I have a data frame that looks like this
data link: https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArOzUuixE-mg6W7zY2Xvgu80dCsL?e=BuP6xM

```
                  letters counts
1                   AAAAAA     21
2                 AAAAAAAA      9
3           AAAAAAAACAAGGA      1
4             AAAAAAAAGAGT      1
5                AAAAAAACA     24
6            AAAAAAACACAAG      1
7             AAAAAAACAGGG     41
8      AAAAAAACAGTCAATCCTA      2
9                 AAAAAAAG     48
10            AAAAAAAGCTGT      2
```

I have millions of rows like this. I have tried the package "smbinning"
but I am not sure how it can be applied to this type of data.
Do you know any other package or how the smbinning might work.

Thank for your time

Comment: Dear Ian, I guess if you use an optimal binning algorithm then the algorithm cuts your data in bins (based on certain criteria) instead of me doing it manually

Comment: Sure there are algorithms. However, you showed us a uniform distribution, and thus there is no need for such an algorithm. Therefore, we need more information about the characteristics of the data, the criteria you're interested in, and the expected output.

Comment: I know data can be a very private thing, so sometimes providing it is difficult. But to have the highest chance of getting an answer that will work for you, we need to know what the data looks like, and what you expect out.

Comment: You are right Ian. I see your point and I appreciate your time to help. Looking forward to our discussion

Comment: When you say "optimal binning", how is "optimal" defined?

Comment: As far as I have understood one way of optimal binning is a binning that allows to see the distribution of your counts. e.g., package("dlookR").
bin <- binning(data1$counts)]. Another way of optimal binning is a binning that allows you to train your model the best